# Text | Image | Text - 1 Horizontal Row - Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

First of all, I will immediately apologise for the fact that it would appear that I am asking the same question which has been answered several times on here already.

Despite spending the last 1-2 hours trying to find the answer, I have caved in and am looking for someone to give it to me, but to also explain **why I was wrong.**

**EDIT**
I can't get the 2 div's of text, and the image in 1 ROW using Bootstrap.

I want TEXT | PIC | TEXT.

Here's the HTML using Bootstrap:

```
            <div class="container">
        <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="MainLeftInfo col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <h3 style="bold">The Story</h3>
            <p>Text Text Text</p>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="PicOfMe col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <img src="Pictures\jacksparrow.jpg" alt="A picture of me!">
                </div>
                <div class="MainRightInfo col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <h3> Interests, Hobbies and Addictions </h3>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Gaming (Xbox & PC)</li>
                            <li>Animals</li>
                            <li>Web Development</li>
                            <li>Red Bull</li>
                            <li>Chocolate</li>
                        </ul>
                    <h3> Location </h3>
                        <p> Cranleigh, Surrey</p>
                    <h3> Skillset (So Far) </h3>
                        <ul>
                            <li>HTML</li>
                            <li>CSS</li>
                            <li>Javascript</li>
                            <li>Responsive Web Design (Bootstrap)</li>
                            <li>Ability to liase and discuss technical concepts with non-technical people</li>
                        </ul>
                </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Heres the CSS:

```
.PicOfMe img {
    border: 20px solid white;
    border-radius: 100%;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Apologies - Please see edit!

Comment: Why would you end up with `TEXT | PIC | TEXT` when your HTML for the row is `(div with an image child) | (div with lists for children)`, and your columns don't equal 12? Do you understand how Bootstrap works?

Comment: I'll admit I'm relatively new to bootstrap.
I apologise if the content of my lists appear to offend you.

I'm not looking for criticism, but an answer.

Comment: Your lists don't offend me. However you should probably spend a little time reading the Bootstrap docs to see how their grid works, and view the source of the examples that they provide. Also `style="bold"` isn't valid.

Answer (score 0):

You just need 1 `container` on a page, and move all `col-*` divs into the the ` like this:

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="MainLeftInfo col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <!-- the story -->
      </div>
      <div class="PicOfMe col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <img src="Pictures\jacksparrow.jpg" alt="A picture of me!">
      </div>
      <div class="MainRightInfo col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <!-- interests -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment about Bootstraps grid system: all `col-*`adds up to 12; probably you want to change `col-md-3` to `col-md-4`? Also, it's not necessary to define the same columns twice. `col-md-4` will create the same as `col-lg-4` on wider screens. Bootstrap works "bottom > up" (or "smaller > large")

See plunkr https://plnkr.co/edit/8zYl7pODUi9bzFicLG19?p=preview